# Override a resource in a Style Trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

I have a `ListBoxItem` Style where I use the normal Foreground and a Resource "GrayBrush2" for highlighting.
When selected the Foreground Property can be changed via the Trigger and Setter of the Style to White. But I also want to override the GrayBrush Resource **locally** to black only when the Item is selected.

Sample Code:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroListBoxItem}">
        <!-- This will override the GrayBrush2 Resource with my local Value. 
        I want tos to be only applies when my Item is selected. -->
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GrayBrush2"
                     Color="{StaticResource HighlightColor}" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}" />
        </Style.Setters>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                 Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}" />
                <!-- Here I want to apply the resources Part dynamically -->
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: you talked about the resource `GrayBrush` but we don't know exactly where that resource is, or you mean it's the `GrayBrush2`?

Comment: Correct. I will change this in my post.